# Question about copying action in a php function

Tags: php, php-8

I am total newbie but I am trying to modify this script:

```
public function fetchProducts($syncAll = true)
{

    $this->library = new B1([
        'apiKey' => $this->settings->get('api_key'),
        'privateKey' => $this->settings->get('private_key')
    ]);
    $i = 0;
    $enableQuantitySync = $this->settings->get('quantity_sync');
    $enableSyncItemName = $this->settings->get('sync_item_name');
    $enableSyncItemPrice = $this->settings->get('sync_item_price');
    $this->items->resetAllB1ReferenceId();
    $page = 0;
    $warehouseId = 7;
    $data = [];
    do {
        $i++;
        try {
            $response = $this->library->request('e-commerce/items/stock', [
                'warehouseId' => $warehouseId,
                'page' => ++$page,
                'pageSize' => 100,
                'filters' => [
                    'groupOp' => 'AND',
                    'rules' => [
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
            $data = $response->getContent();
            foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
                if ($item['code'] != NULL) {
                    $this->items->updateProductReferenceId($item['id'], $item['code']);
                    if ($enableQuantitySync == 1) {
                        $this->items->updateProductQuantity2($item['quantity'], $item['id']);
                    }
                    if ($enableSyncItemName == 1) {
                        $this->items->updateItemName($item['name'], $item['id']);
                    }
                    if ($enableSyncItemPrice == 1) {
                        $this->items->updateItemPrice($item['priceWithoutVat'], $item['id']);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (B1Exception $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        } catch (B1DuplicateException $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        } catch (B1DuplicateException $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        } catch (B1ValidationException $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        } catch (B1ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        } catch (B1InternalErrorException $e) {
            $content = $e->getResponse()->getContent();
            $this->helper->printPre($content['message']);
        }
        echo "$i;";
    } while (isset($data['pages']) && $page <= $data['pages'] && $i < self::MAX_ITERATIONS);
    echo 'OK';
}
```

This script works fine, but I want to add another warehouse id = 2 in this function, so I am trying add this piece of code inside of function:

```
$warehouseId = 2;
$data = [];
do {
    $i++;
    try {
        $response = $this->library->request('e-commerce/items/stock', [
            'warehouseId' => $warehouseId,
            'page' => ++$page,
            'pageSize' => 100,
            'filters' => [
                'groupOp' => 'AND',
                'rules' => [
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $data = $response->getContent();
        foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
            if ($item['code'] != NULL) {
                $this->items->updateProductReferenceId2($item['id'], $item['code']);
                if ($enableQuantitySync == 1) {
                    $this->items->updateProductQuantity2($item['quantity'], $item['id']);
                }
                if ($enableSyncItemName == 1) {
                    $this->items->updateItemName2($item['name'], $item['id']);
                }
                if ($enableSyncItemPrice == 1) {
                    $this->items->updateItemPrice2($item['priceWithoutVat'], $item['id']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting errors.

Can someone help me to figure out a solution for this?

I was trying to add selected code in the function, but I am getting errors.

Comment: If you get errors, you need to tell us what they are. We don't get points for guessing. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: Also please show your attempt to combine the code so it forms a [mre] of the issue with the errors you're getting. Otherwise we may not know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `} while (...)` at the end of the `do` loop you're adding.